# random generation of image from drawable folder without using the image names in android

Tags: android, image, performance, random

i'm trying to do is i have 100 images in my drawable folder ,how can access the images 
 without mansion the all the name how i can display the images.

```
   public Integer[] image= { R.drawable.add,
                          R.drawable.back,
                          R.drawable.ball,
                          R.drawable.edit,
                          R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                          R.drawable.send,
                          R.drawable.setdate,
                          R.drawable.add,
                          R.drawable.backbg,
                          R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                          R.drawable.ball,
                          R.drawable.android,
                          R.drawable.avd,..........



};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the images to a list, and then picking a numbered entry from the list?  Generate the list when you read the directory, and pick a random number up to the list size.  That will give you a single entry from your list, which you can retrieve and display.